# Can I add Click Listener to a custom Toast

Tags: android, onclicklistener, toast, buttonclick, android-toast

I am creating a custom toast for my application. What I need is to add OnClickListener on a button I added on Toast. Everything goes well, I can see the button but it does not respond to OnClick. Any idea.

Example Code:

```
Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
            button.setText("Click Me");
            button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", "nothing");

                }
            });
        button.setLayoutParams(new     ViewGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
        toast.setMargin(0,-80);
        toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.setView(button);  
        toast.show();
```

Further, I have tried by adding onTouchListener to button like this.

```
 button.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ProgressDialog.show(getApplicationContext(), "Hello", "nothing");
        return false;
    }
});
```

But it does not work either.

Comment: instead of toast use a dialog

Comment: Views are not click-able inside Toast so use AlertDialog or popupwindow.

Comment: Using a button on a toast is a bad idea. Use a dialog

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crouton library solved the problem. Hope it would be helpful for someone else too.

https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton

Answer (score 1):

You should not include a `Button` in the `Toast`. Just show the button, then hide it after a length of time. You can do this by adding a `RelativeLayout` over top of your existing layout. Something like this should work:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <include layout="@layout/main" /><!-- References your existing layout file -->
    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/toast_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:text="@string/click_me"
        android:onClick="showDialog" /><!-- Should reference a String resource "click me"-->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Now create the *Toast* effect, add the following method to your `Activity`:

```
public void showDialog(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.toast_button) {
        ProgressDialog.show(this, "Hello", "nothing");
    }
}
```

Then in `onCreate`, show the button *like* a `Toast`:

```
final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.toast_button);
//optionally add some animations for fading in
b.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Timer t = new Timer();
t.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //optionally add some animations for fading out
                b.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
        });
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is not the case Phil. Button does not receive click event.

Comment: @Adnan see my revised answer